# Nesting success (binomial glmm) in r

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models

I am running a GLMM using `glmer()` in R:

```
glmer(survive ~ fyear + site + fyear * site.x + (1|fyear),
family = binomial(link = logexp(shaffer.sub$exposure)),
data = shaffer.sub)
```

where survive is 0 or 1 depending if the nest was successful or not. [Here](http://pastebin.com/c1hMx01q) you can see what the data looks like:

```
structure(list(id = structure(1:7, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), year.x = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1994", "1995", "1999"), class = "factor"), 
    survive = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), fyear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1994", "1995", "1999"), class = "factor"), 
    site.x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "year.x", "survive", 
"fyear", "site.x"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

but I get this warning message:

```
*Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0299425 (tol = 0.001, component 12)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?*
```

I was told I should not use the same random factor as a fixed effect on the same model.

At the end, I would like to have an output where I can see year, site and the interaction year:site effects. Like in an ANOVA table (is this possible? I've been trying to use `summary(aov(model))` but this doesn't work; `anova(model)` does not either.

I get this error for the `aov()` command:

```
*Error in summary`(aov(syearXsite))` : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in if (fixed.only) { : argument is not interpretable as logical*
```

How can I see the effect of this variables on survival?

Comment: thanks alexforrence!

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you not to use a categorical input variable (`fyear`) as both a fixed and a random effect was correct.  It's hard to know exactly what to recommend, it depends on the number of years and sites you have in your data set (is the data you linked to *all* of your data (I hope not), or just the first few rows?  How many years and how many sites and how many total observations do you have?)

If you want to treat year as random and site as fixed (which would be sensible if you have only two sites (`N` vs `S` as seen in your data) and quite a few years, e.g. more than 5) then you could fit:

```
g1 <- glmer(survive~site.x+(site.x|fyear),
      family=binomial(link=logexp(shaffer.sub$exposure)),
      data=shaffer.sub)
```

I don't know what `site` vs `site.x` are: I only see `site.x` in your data snippet.

To get information, try `summary(g1)`.  (That will only give you variances for random effects, not for fixed effects; GLMMs don't operate in the same "variance explained" mode as ANOVA does, in particular because the variances explained by different terms usually do *not* add up to the total variance.)

Comment: Hello Ben, I have 11 years and hundreds of observations for some years. In total my dataset is 4742 observations and 2 sites (north and south). I'm interested also in the year as a fixed effect. True, it is site=site.x, it comes from the output when I linked the output survival. Is there a way to get the effect of the  year, site and the interaction year*site from this model? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The model works perfect! but I guess then it is not possible to get an interaction yearXsite. The intercept I understand is the year (p-value=<2e-16 ***), so if it is significant nesting success varies over the years (i.e. is different), and for the site (p-value=0.505) nesting success is the same for both sites? but what can I say about the estimates?
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   4.6105     0.5134   8.981   <2e-16 ***
site.xS      -0.2855     0.4281  -0.667    0.505    
Thanks!